# Visual Studio 2010: How to set build platform to Active(x86)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

Most of the projects in a solution allow the option to select a build platform of Active(x86)

[image]

However one does not:

[image]

I cant work out why. They are all VS2010 projects targeting .Net Framework 4. I thought maybe the offending project was referencing something 64bit but it's not so I dunno? Any thoughts?

Comment: I have seen that doing ASP.NET MVC projects...is that what this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think setting Project Properties from Configuration Manager may help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be set here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjubz.png

quote picture form http://en.morzel.net/post/2011/09/16/BadImageFormatException-x86-i-x64.aspx

Comment: I have (and always) set the target platform using that drop down you've referred too. No problem there but the top dialog's don't change. Now i'm wondering if I even understand the purpose of the top drop downs. The seem to have an effect on output directories etc for builds which can be manually altered but it'd be great if the drop down actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 64bit OS installed then Visual Studio will show in Configuration manager